# How do I publish to a solace temp queue created in another process

Tags: java, solace

I have a Java application that consumes messages from a queue.  I also have a test client that runs as a separate Java application and publishes messages to that queue.

To test the listener application locally, I have it create a temp queue and listen to that queue. Following is the listener code that I used for Tibco:

```
session = connection.createQueueSession(false, javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

Queue queue;
if (useTemporaryRequestQueue) {
    queue = session.createTemporaryQueue();
    requestQueueName = queue.getQueueName();  // $TMP$.server.UID
} else {
    queue = session.createQueue(requestQueueName);
}

receiver = session.createReceiver(queue);
receiver.setMessageListener(this);
```

In my test client, I was then able to use the following code to connect to the Tibco request queue:

```
session = connection.createQueueSession(false, javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
requestQueue = session.createQueue(requestQueueName); // $TMP$.server.UID
responseQueue = session.createTemporaryQueue();
```

When I try this createQueue call with the Solace temp queue name, it fails:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-durable endpoints are not allowed as an argument to provision
at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.JCSMPBasicSession.provision(JCSMPBasicSession.java:1183)
at com.solacesystems.jms.SolSession.createQueue(SolSession.java:492)
```

Is there another way to connect to the temp queue from my test client?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create the queue in your publisher.

Take a look at `RRGuaranteedRequester.java` and `RRGuaranteedReplier.java` in the API samples where the requester creates a temporary queue as the `ReplyTo` destination, and the replier replies by publishing guaranteed messages to that temporary queue.

In RRGuaranteedReplier.java:

```
private void sendReply(XMLMessage request, XMLMessage reply) throws Exception {
    Destination replyDestination = null;
    replyDestination = request.getReplyTo();
    ...        
    producer.send(reply, replyDestination);
}
```

In RRGuaranteedRequester.java:

```
void doRequest(Destination requestDestination, Operation operation, int leftHandOperand, int rightHandOperand) throws Exception {
    Queue replyQueue = session.createTemporaryQueue();
    ...
    request.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
    request.setReplyTo(replyQueue);
    ...
}
```

You can download the full set of samples that's included in the API from http://dev.solace.com/downloads/.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the use case I'm trying to solve. My test client does exactly what you described, but for independent testing I want to use a temp queue on both sides of the conversation like I was able to do with Tibco.

Comment: I assume you mean a temp queue on EACH side, not a temp queue that's shared between the two. But one side will have to tell the other the name of their queue, which request-reply will nicely solve that. If somehow, you magically know the name of the temp queue, one hackish way is to use JCSMPSession.createTemporaryQueue(String hack). Here, hack = tmp_queue.name().substring(tmp_queue.name().lastIndexOf('/')+1). Be warned that this hack may not work in other versions.

Comment: Forgot to mention that hackish way is only for the underlying JCSMP API, not JMS.

Comment: In my example there is a temp queue on each side, but one of them is shared as I tried to show in my edits (look for $TMP$.server.UID). Since this use of a temp queue is a bit of a hack to start with, I'll see if your hack will do what I need.

Comment: Using the JCSMP API will require a full rewrite of my test client, since all of my other code uses JMS and JNDI.  I'll need to look for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is an api to create temporary queue in solace but that doesn't take queue name as an argument instead there will be temporary queue name assigned in return. Try the sample below:

```
    Queue queue = session.createTemporaryQueue(); // create a queue like '#P2P/QTMP/v:solace/2d78591c-f465-4bac-9a20-e09c04641538'
    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
    connection.start();
    TextMessage testMessage = session.createTextMessage("sample message");
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
    producer.send(testMessage);
    TextMessage msg = (TextMessage)consumer.receive();
```

Refer this link for some info on request-response model:
http://dev.solace.com/get-started/jms-tutorials/request-reply_jms/

Alternatively you can consider using an temporary topic to publish from test client and use a fixed queue to do wildcard card subscription of the temp topic.

http://dev.solace.com/get-started/jms-tutorials/request-reply_jms/

Comment: I added sample code to my question to (hopefully) make the problem more clear. The first part of your answer is not what I need, but maybe you could elaborate on the temporary topic idea.

Comment: In case of temporary topic solace allows you to create a topic at run time, you can use a namespace for your temporary topic something like /temp/test/{testid} and you can make the queue to subscribe the name space q.test --> subscribes to /temp/test/>. Here the '>' indicates wildcard expression. At run time your topic will be like /temp/test/1234 and all the message to this topic goes to q.test. You can give it try if it fits your purpose.